# Where if there's a match

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table I'm selecting from, which logs "Signatures" from logins.

The table is like so:

```
| Int| VARCHAR  | Guid   | Bit    | Int |  NVARCHAR(MAX)
| ID | UserName | UserId | Signed | Rec | additional info etc...
| -- | -------- | ------ | ------ | --- | ---------------------
| 1  | Bob      | 12     | 0      | 100 | sasdd
| 2  | Steve    | 14     | 1      | 100 | asretg
| 3  | GROUP: 2 | 76     | 0      | 101 | This is a group of logins
| 4  | Bob      | 12     | 1      | 101 | asdfasd
```

So column 5 is the target ID to which it's been signed.

To build a list of unsigned items for a specific user (Bob) was pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT Rec FROM tbl_Sigs WHERE Signed = 0 And UserId = '12'
```

Now, I've added login groups to this list, as in item `3` - In this example, the group has both logins in it and I'm able in code to pull from the login, which group it has access to, so the statement becomes:

```
SELECT Rec FROM tbl_Sigs WHERE (Signed = 0 And UserId = '12')
    OR UserId IN (76,77,78)
```

This works, but in the example will select record `100` and `101`.

What I would like is to only select record `100` for Bob, because I have a match for `101` because of "GROUP: 2" (Which will always be unsigned), however "Bob" has signed record `101` already, hence doesn't need it in his list.

What I can't figure out if how to put that condition into the where clause, I could do it in C# once I have the dataset but would prefer a pure SQL way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a NOT EXISTS clause?

```
DECLARE @tbl_Sigs TABLE (
    ID INT,
    UserName VARCHAR(50),
    UserId INT, --Not a GUID!
    Signed BIT,
    Rec INT,
    AdditionalInfo VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl_Sigs VALUES (1, 'Bob', 12, 0, 100, 'sasdd');
INSERT INTO @tbl_Sigs VALUES (2, 'Steve', 14, 1, 100, 'asretg');
INSERT INTO @tbl_Sigs VALUES (3, 'GROUP: 2', 76, 0, 101, 'This is a group of logins');
INSERT INTO @tbl_Sigs VALUES (4, 'Bob', 12, 1, 101, 'asdfasd');
--So column 5 is the target ID to which it's been signed.
--To build a list of unsigned items for a specific user (Bob) was pretty straight forward:
SELECT Rec FROM @tbl_Sigs WHERE Signed = 0 And UserId = '12';

--Now, I've added login groups to this list, as in item 3 - In this example, the group has both logins in it and I'm able in code to pull from the login, which group it has access to, so the statement becomes:
SELECT Rec FROM @tbl_Sigs r1 WHERE (Signed = 0 And UserId = '12') OR UserId IN (76, 77, 78)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @tbl_Sigs r2 WHERE r2.Rec = r1.Rec AND r2.UserId = '12' AND r2.Signed = 1);
```

Comment: I was almost there but just needed to see how you can use the `r1` / `r2` tables to join the where clause to the select, fantastic thank you!